# How to integrate Linphone SDK with Existing Swift Project?

Tags: ios, swift, linphone, linphone-sdk

I have followed to this instruction about how to integrate with linphone SDK

- http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone

After that, I follow with this intruction

- https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/iOS/

I have done with the final build Linphone SDK file, so next is the integration process. I didn't find any document or any suggestion for how to implement with the swift project

The document of liblinphone(Does not include how to integration just the class function)

- https://www.linphone.org/snapshots/docs/liblinphone/swift/index.html

Comment: Have you integrated linphone SDK in your project?

Comment: Yes, I'm already integrated linphone SDK in my project but still get stuck of how to use their SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you have installed the pod for linphone with version 4.2. If not then please have a look at this.

```
source "https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git"
source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"

def basic_pods
  if ENV['PODFILE_PATH'].nil?
    pod 'linphone-sdk', '4.2'
    else
    pod 'linphone-sdk', :path => ENV['PODFILE_PATH']  # loacl sdk
  end
end
```

Step 1-> You need to add a bridge file and import the below files in that.

```
#include "linphone/lpconfig.h"
#include "linphone/linphonecore.h"
#include "linphone/linphonecore_utils.h"
```

Step 2-> After that create 1 `.h` and `.m` file and in that copy all the call related functionality from the linphone project like outgoing call, incoming call and so on.

Step 3-> Create the object which you have entered the name of `.h` file.

Step4-> Call that functionality with the help of your object variable.

Comment: For step 2 do I need to create ```.m``` file?

Comment: Yes in that you need to mention all the Method which linphone used like Outgoing call, Hold call.

Comment: Pretty clear, do you have any example project or any public git repo that used linphone? I'm kinda new with this lib. For make sure that I'll use the necessary Method. My needs are to make it callable and can make a video call

Comment: Yes, I did it in one of the project. But I can't share a full project with you. If you wanna help so i can help you here.

Comment: Which document of linphone you have followed on?

Comment: No one document is perfect. So I was trying to debug and implement in my project.

Comment: You can follow this project: https://github.com/hamzaozturk/linphone-swift-demo

Comment: @HamzaÖztürk can you help me for video call in swift 5?

Comment: @ChandanJee you can create an issue in my repo. I will try to create an example for you.

Comment: @HamzaÖztürk Thanks for reply. yes created. You can check.